# Mlib RandomForest (Spark 2.0) predict a single vector

Tags: random, apache-spark, machine-learning, random-forest

After training a RandomForestRegressor in PipelineModel using mlib and DataFrame (Spark 2.0) 
I loaded the saved model into my RT environment in order to predict using the model, each request 
is handled and transform through the loaded PipelineModel but in the process I had to convert the 
single request vector to a one row DataFrame using spark.createdataframe all of this takes around 700ms!

comparing to 2.5ms if I uses mllib RDD RandomForestRegressor.predict(VECTOR). 
Is there any way to use the new mlib to predict a a single vector without converting to DataFrame or do something else to speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe based `org.apache.spark.ml.regression.RandomForestRegressionModel` also takes a `Vector` as input. I don't think you need to convert a vector to dataframe for every call.

Here is how I think you code should work.

```
    //load the trained RF model
    val rfModel = RandomForestRegressionModel.load("path")  
    val predictionData = //a dataframe containing a column 'feature' of type Vector
    predictionData.map { row => 
        Vector feature = row.getAs[Vector]("feature")
        Double result = rfModel.predict(feature)
        (feature, result)
    }
```